# の to prevent repetition of が

Tags: nuances, particles, syntax

In the following sentence

東京は冬になると、北風の強い日が多いです。

is it correct that 北風の強い replaces the more obvious option 北風が強い in order to avoid close repetition of が？

So if the following が in 日が多い had not been there to interfere, would it have been more natural to use  北風が強い ?

Or do the two options actually differ with some semantic nuance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why the expression of 「北風の強い」 in  `東京は冬になると、北風の強い日が多いです。` is rather [scientific reason](https://kids.gakken.co.jp/box/nazenani/pdf/10_kisyou/X1110112.pdf) than the syntax.

We don't have to emphasize 北風:the wind from north in winter because the Eurasian continent is cold in winter and it it higher pressure than the area around Japan. 
Therefore, the wind blows from north(or north western) of Japan, especially Siberia.

We even have the song called [『北風小僧の寒太郎』](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNhuzeYEpIE) and are probably getting used to associate "北風" with "cold and winter" by the melody.

Probably in spring or autumn, if it has been still cold or getting cold from time to time,
you might hear 「北風がまだ強い日/強くなる日」on the weather forecast news.

Normally we expect the wind from tropical zone on the south(south east) of Japan in hot summer.